# What am I doing wrong in this ASPxPageControl? (dev express)

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

Here is what I have.  I am trying to use Developer Express ASPxPageControl.  I want to only load the first TabPage (and WebUserControl it contains) when the page is loaded and then when I click on subsequent tabs, load those WebUserControls.  I have found documentation [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q348532.aspx)  and other places telling me to

> set the ASPxPageControl.AutoPostBack property to false, and ASPxPageControl.EnableCallBacks set to true

However, this is not working for me.  I have verified with the debugger that when the main page is loaded, each of my WebUserControls are also loading.  Am I misunderstanding the idea of the ASPxPageControl??

```
<dxtc:ASPxPageControl ID="ASPxPageControl1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
    EnableCallBacks="True"
     AutoPostBack="false" >
    <TabPages>
        <dxtc:TabPage Text="Detail" Name="tabDetail">
            <ContentCollection>
                <dxw:ContentControl ID="ContentControl3" runat="server">

                    <uc13:WUCDetail ID="WUCDetail" runat="server" />

                </dxw:ContentControl>
            </ContentCollection>
        </dxtc:TabPage>
        <dxtc:TabPage Text="Room" Name="tabRoom">
            <ContentCollection>
                <dxw:ContentControl ID="ContentControl4" runat="server">

                    <uc11:WUCRoom ID="WUCRoom" runat="server" />

                </dxw:ContentControl>
            </ContentCollection>
        </dxtc:TabPage>
        <dxtc:TabPage Text="Mailers" Name="tabMailers">
            <ContentCollection>
                <dxw:ContentControl ID="ContentControl5" runat="server">

                    <uc10:WUCMailers ID="WUCMailers" runat="server" />

                </dxw:ContentControl>
            </ContentCollection>
        </dxtc:TabPage>     
     </TabPages>

</dxtc:ASPxPageControl>
```

Comment: Are those "WebUserControls" bound to data?

Comment: Yes.  So I am trying to only query the data when I switch tabs, and not on the initial page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, this is not working for me. I have verified with the debugger
>   that when the main page is loaded, each of my WebUserControls are also
>   loading. Am I misunderstanding the idea of the ASPxPageControl??

I'm afraid you are misunderstanding the idea of the example ["How to create and load an active tab's content on a callback"](http://www.devexpress.com/example=E10). The main idea of this example is to create and load an active tab's content on a callback.
But you've specified content for all pages directly in markup. Thus these controls will be created and loaded in any cases. Please, create an empty tabpages and then use the approach demonstrated in this example to create and load page's content only when active tab changed.

Comment: You are correct.  I inherited this code and since I am relatively new to devx, I assumed that the original concept was solid.  Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.  I implemented the example and all now works as expected.  

A quick word to anyone else in the future trying to implement this:  Since I am dynamically loading webusercontrols that have child controls, I was getting weird "The target 'X' for the callback could not be found or did not implement ICallbackEventHandler" errors.  The fix is easy -->  http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18291.aspx

Comment: DmitryG : You are Awesome.I'm cracking my head since morning.