# callback in one aspxgridview causes all gridviews to databind

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, devexpress

I have a aspxgridview with details row.
in detils row of this gridview, there are about 10 aspxgridviews. whenever one of this grids cause callback by clicking edit/new/delete , other gridview also databound i.e hit database. this cause performance issue.
Is there a way to disable databinding on other aspxgridview?

tanks.

[image: screenshot of grid with detail's grids]

Comment: Is that ASPxPageControl in detail row?

Comment: yes, it is page control with several tab pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find a solution here:
[ASPxPageControl - Page Load of all TabPages](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q253866.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tab content lazy loading. Look [here for example](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E10.aspx) and [here for further explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235228/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-this-aspxpagecontrol-dev-express).

Comment: your linked example works, however i want there is a refresh button on each tab so when user hits button, tabs content refreshed again, can u give me source code for this. tanks